Globally configure dotnet build parallelism
The dotnet build command by default uses all cores. On an older machine, that makes
it completely unresponsive.
It can be configured by passing -m (or -maxCpuCount) to msbuild: dotnet build -m:3
Is there a way to save that configuration (-m:x) at the machine level, so it does not need to be specified every time?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-response-files?view=vs-2022#msbuildrsp

@lonix, In general, we can configure the maximum CPU count at the machine level by setting an environment variable.
You can set the DOTNET_MSBUILD_CLI_OPTIONS environment variables to include the -m option:
On Windows::
Run this command in Command Prompt or PowerShell:
setx DOTNET_MSBUILD_CLI_OPTIONS "-m:3"

This will automatically apply the -m:3 option to every dotnet build invocation.
Hope this approach helps.
